# MySQL error: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'm having the following PHP code:

```
try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT nume,prenume FROM candidati');
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $aux = $row->nume.' '.$row->prenume;
        $st = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM votanti WHERE consiliul_local=?');
        $st->execute(array($aux));
        while($r = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            $s = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO rezultate SET obtinute=:o WHERE nume=:n AND prenume=:p");
            $s->bindParam(':o',$r->total,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $s->bindParam(':n',$row->nume,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $s->bindParam(':p',$row->prenume,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $s->execute();
        }
    }
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

And the following class:

```
class DB{
    public static function connect($engine,$host,$user,$pass,$name){
        try{
            $dbh = new PDO("$engine:host=$host;dbname=$name;charset=utf8",$user,$pass);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
            return $dbh;
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I execute the first piece of code, it sends this error message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE nume=? AND prenume=?' at line 1

Can you give me a tip on how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: `INSERT INTO rezultate` did you mean `update rezultate` ?

Comment: Did you mean to do an `UPDATE` instead?

Comment: yes... there should be an update instead. embarassing :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`INSERT` statements do not have a `WHERE` clause. You need to use `UPDATE` instead.

```
$s = $db->prepare("UPDATE rezultate SET obtinute=:o WHERE nume=:n AND prenume=:p");
```